# Sharing folder with video player using samba

Tags: macos, smb

I'm trying to share macbook folder with `asus o'play`.

OS X recently updated to Yosemite.

Here is errors in log:

```
Nov 19 15:19:25 Mac.local digest-service[1046]: digest-request: uid=0
Nov 19 15:19:25 Mac.local digest-service[1046]: digest-request: netr probe 0
Nov 19 15:19:25 Mac.local digest-service[1046]: digest-request: init request
Nov 19 15:19:25 Mac.local digest-service[1046]: digest-request: init return domain: MAC server: MAC indomain was: <NULL>
Nov 19 15:19:25 Mac.local digest-service[1046]: digest-request: uid=0
Nov 19 15:19:25 Mac.local digest-service[1046]: digest-request: init request
Nov 19 15:19:25 Mac.local digest-service[1046]: digest-request: init return domain: MAC server: MAC indomain was: <NULL>
Nov 19 15:19:25 Mac.local digest-service[1046]: digest-request: uid=0
Nov 19 15:19:25 Mac.local digest-service[1046]: digest-request: init request
Nov 19 15:19:25 Mac.local digest-service[1046]: digest-request: init return domain: MAC server: MAC indomain was: <NULL>
Nov 19 15:19:25 Mac.local digest-service[1046]: digest-request: uid=0
Nov 19 15:19:25 Mac.local digest-service[1046]: digest-request: od failed with 2 proto=ntlmv1-with-v2-session
Nov 19 15:19:25 Mac.local digest-service[1046]: digest-request: user=WORKGROUP\OPlayer
Nov 19 15:19:25 Mac.local digest-service[1046]: digest-request: kdc failed with -1561745600 proto=ntlmv1
Nov 19 15:19:25 Mac.local digest-service[1046]: digest-request: guest failed with -1561745590 proto=ntlmv1-with-v2-session
Nov 19 15:19:26 Mac.local digest-service[1046]: digest-request: uid=0
Nov 19 15:19:26 Mac.local digest-service[1046]: digest-request: init request
Nov 19 15:19:26 Mac.local digest-service[1046]: digest-request: init return domain: MAC server: MAC indomain was: <NULL>
Nov 19 15:19:26 Mac.local digest-service[1046]: digest-request: uid=0
Nov 19 15:19:26 Mac.local digest-service[1046]: digest-request: init request
Nov 19 15:19:26 Mac.local digest-service[1046]: digest-request: init return domain: MAC server: MAC indomain was: <NULL>
Nov 19 15:19:26 Mac.local digest-service[1046]: digest-request: uid=0
Nov 19 15:19:26 Mac.local digest-service[1046]: digest-request: init request
Nov 19 15:19:26 Mac.local digest-service[1046]: digest-request: init return domain: MAC server: MAC indomain was: <NULL>
Nov 19 15:19:26 Mac.local digest-service[1046]: digest-request: uid=0
Nov 19 15:19:26 Mac.local digest-service[1046]: digest-request: od failed with 2 proto=ntlmv1-with-v2-session
Nov 19 15:19:26 Mac.local digest-service[1046]: digest-request: user=MYGROUP\OPlayer
Nov 19 15:19:26 Mac.local digest-service[1046]: digest-request: kdc failed with -1561745600 proto=ntlmv1
Nov 19 15:19:26 Mac.local digest-service[1046]: digest-request: guest failed with -1561745590 proto=ntlmv1-with-v2-session
```

There are some [workarounds](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6613032), but they are for desktops. How I can login to mac using, when there are no access to player settings?

Comment: Is there a reason the workarounds you mentioned for desktops would not work? File/folder sharing is the same for laptops and desktops in OSX. Is the Asus running Windows 7?

Comment: @rchrdg Asus is Video Player. It's not laptop. It hasn't settings for samba in UI at least.